# how to install lua into codespaces?

Tags: github, lua, codespaces

Github codespaces looks awesome but I can't  install lua.

[image: cant install lua]

I think I need a debian repo containing lua (which i would add to sources.list).

But I write to ask

- is that the right approach?
- where is that debian repo?

Comment: are you sure it's not called lua54 or lua-5.4 or something like that? or just lua?

Comment: You are 100% right. Problem solved.   "sudo apt-get install lua" gave me a list of packages. I could install lua5.3 from that list. Thanks for your help.

Comment: lua5.3 is not the same as lua5.4